# Extracting a specific value from a specific xml tag using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

My xml:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I need a regex to extract "Don't forget me this weekend!" in the  tag and also if the  tag exists in python using regex.

I have written a code, but I am not able to figure out the regex expression.

Comment: I think you should take a look into regex's and then come with doubts about the regex you have, if any

Comment: I think you should include your code.

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Are you sure regex is the correct tool? It's usually not the correct way to parse xml or html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic solution:

```
import re  


data  = """
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>"""

found = re.findall('<body>(.*)</body>', data)

if found:
  for x in found:
    print(x)

>> Don't forget me this weekend!
```